# Второй input в PyCharm не работает (возвращает пустую строку)

Tags: python, pycharm

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = input()
if c == '-':
    print(a-b)
elif c == '+':
    print(a+b)
elif c == '*':
    print(a*b)
elif b == 0:
    print("На ноль делить нельзя!")
elif c == '/':
    print(a/b)
else:
    print('Неверная операция')
```

Не могу понять почему код не работает. Пишет

```
C:\Users\1\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/1/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/main.py
4
4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\1\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    b = int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Хотя в браузере ( онлайн версия питона ) и через консоль все работает отлично.

Comment: `print(eval(input()))` и вводите примеры типа '5 * 3' и тому подобное и все будет считаться... (не шутка)... А что касается кода то вы пытаетесь ввести пустую строку в переменную b а потом привести ее к int, о чем обработчик Вам и сообщает

Comment: Нет это не так. Если было бы как вы говорите 1 строка уже показала бы ошибку, а не 2 строка. Тут больше вопрос про пайчарм почему так он выдает? Попробуйте этот код запустить в браузере все будет работать. А у меня на компьютере в пайчарме нет.

Comment: @Namerek Не советую рекомендовать eval неопытным программистам на Python, тем более, запихивая в него input, это невероятно небезопасно, и если изначально не знать о возможностях данной функции, можно создать немыслимые уязвимости.

Comment: Данный код, что в браузере, что в PC работает отлично, если не пытаться передать в первые два аргумента, что-то кроме числа

Comment: Друзья в том то и дело что он не работает в PyCharme у ! МЕНЯ! На компьютере. У других он работает, а на моем компьютере нет. Вот я и прошу у вас совета как сделать так что бы он работал? Может в настройках пацчарма что не так

Comment: Работает код через браузер, через консоль,. Но у меня в пайчарме этот код не работает.

Comment: Может в двойных кавычках причина у print b

Comment: Аркадий вы вопрос читали? Код работает ВЕЗДЕ .  Кроме пайчарма на моем компьютере.

Comment: Кстати через дебагер код работает. А через быстрый запуск нет.

Comment: @Bol4onok, не советуйте, дело Ваше, я не против

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Это чисто [баг PyCharm](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-54238/STDIN-is-lost-for-a-second-input-call). Исправлен в версии PyCharm 2022.1.2.

1. В дебагере - не воспроизводится
2. Если включить эмуляцию консоли - не воспроизводится
3. При запуске из терминала - не воспроизводится

То есть только при стандартном запуске.
Пробовал на версиях питона 3.10.4 и 3.9.12 (Windows 11)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

До исправления в самом PyCharm быстро поправить можно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не подскажите как убрать?

Comment: @veles008, дополнил пост

Comment: Спасибо большое. Прийду с работы попробую!

Comment: @veles008 Так вы попробовали? Если работает - пометьте ответ, как подходящий специальной галочкой. Если нет - напишите об этом в комментарии. А то вопрос теперь висит в непонятном статусе - вроде и есть ответ, но непонятно, подходит ли он.

Comment: @CrazyElf Все сделал все работает.