# Вторая переменная не присваивает данные после нажатия ENTER

Tags: python, pycharm

После переустановки Виндовс и PyCarm столкнулся с проблемой, например - нужно ввести последовательно 2 числа, пишем первое - Ентер, пишем второе -Enter. на выходе вторая переменная пустая.

```
a = input()
b = input()
print(a, b)
```

на выходе получаю только значение переменной 'a'

если вставляю сразу 2 строки и нажимаю Enter, то всё работает

Comment: Сегодня кто-то про такое уже писал, поищите поиском. У `PyCharm` реально какой-то глюк. Там нужно эмуляцию терминала что ли в опциях включить.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1410299/480328

Comment: @CrazyElf - Вы необыкновенно крутой! Такую бажину с первого взгляда узнать!