# Почему появляется Value error base 10?

Tags: python, pycharm

После введённого ниже стандартного кода

```
a = int(input())
bc = int(input())
d = int(input())
e = int(input())
```

PyCharm выдаёт ошибку:
**ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''**

в интерпретаторе я ввожу обычные числа: к примеру, "1", затем "2".
Не важно, сколько переменных у меня в коде, и не важно, какое целое число я ввожу: всегда на втором элементе вылазит ошибка Value Error. Пробелы и текстовые элементы не ввожу.

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Используйте поиск по SO. Все это много раз уже обсуждалось - баг PyCharm.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1410280/178576