# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10 при рабочем коде

Tags: python

Пытаюсь написать программу(в рамках начального курса), которая принимает на вход три значения и сохраняет полученные значения в список.
Писал данный код на курсах - все работало, попробовал на дом. компьютере - выскакивает ошибка после второго ввода input'а.

На картинке видно, что код работал.

```
name, surname, age = input(), input(), int(input())
print([name, surname, age])


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Kileta/Downloads/Telegram Desktop/main (2).py", line 14, in <module>
    name, surname, age = input(), input(), int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'qwe'
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А можете показать набор данных, при котором на Вашем ПК код не работает?

Comment: А можете поискать по сайту SO аналогичную проблему прежде чем вопрос размещать? Я уже лично раз пять писал про подобный баг PуCharm. И кроме меня еще раз десять писали...Запустите в IDLE для начала свой код и вот если не будет работать, то возвращайтесь.

Comment: Тьфу ты, забыл про это :(

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1410280/%d0%92%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9-input-%d0%b2-pycharm-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83