# int(input()) invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' -

Tags: python-3.x

обучаюсь и решаю простые задачи и одна из задач - это посчитать сумму 3-х компьютеров состоящих из мышки, клавиатуры, монитора и мышки. У меня получился вот такой код:

```
monitor = int(input())
block = int(input())
keyboard = int(input())
mouse = int(input())

cost = (monitor + block + keyboard + mouse)*3
print(cost)
```

И мне выдает ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\apexp\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\study.py", line 2, in <module>
    block = int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Лучше прикладывать полную трассу ошибки :) А насчет ошибки: один из `input()` у вас вернул пустую строку, а `int('')` вызывает такую ошибку

Comment: Вы случайно не на PyCharm это делаете? Вроде бы ещё вчера или позавчера был примерно такой же вопрос, проблема в баге PyCharm, который пока ещё не исправлен. Да, кстати, сам код верный, но на будущее советую пролистать вопросы с примерно такой же тематикой на SO или на RuSO

Comment: Да, использую PyCharm, просто очень много уже облазил всякого и отчаялся, поэтому сразу сюда вопрос написал

Comment: P.S. Судя по пути файлу, это точно PyCharm, тогда моё предположение выше действительно верно

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1410280/%d0%92%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9-input-%d0%b2-pycharm-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83 — вот пример похожего сообщения