# всем привет, помогите разобраться что не так с кодом (вопрос из песочници pithon)

Tags: python

Почему в строке вывода только один результат?

```
name = input ('Как Вас зовут? ' )
age = int(input('Cкoлькo Вам лет? '))
income = float(input('Kaкoй у Вас доход? '))

print ('Вот данные, которые Вы ввели:')
print ('Имя:', name)
print ('Возраст:', age)
print ('Доход:', income)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот как в книжке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что за вебсайт, собственно говоря? Или что это?

P.S. Вы это Пеинтом картинку срезали или что?

Comment: А Вы вводить что-то на эту строку пробовали?

Comment: да скриншот с сайта, но на пайчаре тоже самое

Comment: Возможно, что Вам нужно обновить PyCharm до последней версии
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1410280/%d0%92%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9-input-%d0%b2-pycharm-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83/1410299#1410299