# Непонятная зависимость буфера ввода от выходного потока (Java)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TestClass2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int drop;
        String str;

        do {
            drop = System.in.read();
        } while(drop != (int)'\n');

        //System.out.println();
        str = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Вопрос простой. Почему, если раскомментировать строку после цикла, сканер исправно возвращает переменной str данные с консоли? А если оставить строку закомментированной, то переменная получает значение пустой строки?

Уточнение1. Эффект имеет место в IntelliJ Idea Build #IC-221.5591.52, built on May 10, 2022. При использовании Notepad++ и cmd код выполняется ожидаемым образом.

Уточнение2. Апдейт IDE на последнюю версию решил проблему. Возможно, помог бы и простой перезапуск. К сожалению, не проверил. Сразу обновил.

Comment: Возможно это тот же баг что и в PyCharm: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1410280/%d0%92%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9-input-%d0%b2-pycharm-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83

Comment: Обновил идею, теперь все ОК. Спасибо! Вы очень помогли участием.