# Прерывается заполнение ArrayList

Tags: java, intellij-idea, arraylist

Что-то лыжи не едут. Вроде раньше так делал и все работало, но могу и обмануть. Сейчас заполнение прерывается на вводе второй строки. В список попадает только первое значение, но если раскомментировать "System.out.println(input);", то все работает как задумано и заполнение прекращается только при пустом вводе.

```
public static ArrayList<String> recordList() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while (true) {
            String input = reader.readLine();
            if (input.isEmpty()){
                break;
            }else{
                list.add(input);
                //System.out.println(input);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: Все у вас правильно работает, я проверил у себя. Ничего не надо расскоментировать.

Comment: Блин, но у меня на компе прерывается. А в чем может быть дело, нет мыслей на этот счет?

Comment: Запускаете в Intellij IDEA?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, Да! Только что проверил через командную строку - все нормально работает. Проблема только в IDEA.

Comment: Тот же баг что и в PyCharm: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1410280. Вот ещё этот баг: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1430844

Comment: Действительно проблема была в самой IDEA. Поставил свежую версию и все заработало.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в самой IDEA. Поставил свежую версию и все заработало.