# Не выводится текст при множественном вводе командой input в pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

При использовании команды input несколько раз подряд и вывода переменных командой print некоторые переменные не отображаются на терминале, но нет никаких ошибок [image: К примеру если вводить 4 переменных то уже при вводе третей переменной, идет выполнение команды print]

Comment: Например если вводить 4 переменных то к уже на третий переменной идет выполнение команды print! Ввожу переменные enter ом!

Comment: Обновите PyCharm

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Второй input в PyCharm не работает (возвращает пустую строку)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1410280/1365)

Comment: Сообщите хоть, помогло обновление или нет, а то может это какая-то новая проблема.

Comment: Спасибо большое @insolor обновил PyCharm помогло!