# Пытаюсь написать консольную игру в PyCharm, а он отказывается перемещать каретку по тому, что уже было выведено на консоль

Tags: python, python-3.x, разработка-игр, pycharm

На это:

```
import os
import curses
import sys

#a - двумерный массив 4х5
def printA():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    for i in range(5):
        print(a[i][0], a[i][1], a[i][2], a[i][3], a[i][4])

   

curses.setupterm()#возврат каретки на строку выше
os.write(sys.stdout.fileno(), curses.tigetstr('cuu1'))  # Upline(cursor up)
```

PyCharm выдаёт такое:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\79107\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 17, in 
> os.write(sys.stdout.fileno(), curses.tigetstr('cuu1'))  # Upline(cursor up)
> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'NoneType'

Хотя в repl it всё работает (там у меня проблемы с библиотекой keyboard). Пожалуйста, подскажите, как в PyCarm двигать каретку вверх по уже выведенному тексту так, чтобы этот текст можно было менять.

[image: Пытаюсь включить эмуляцию консоли]

[image]

[image: результат]

Comment: В настройках терминала PyCharm включите эмуляцию консоли.

Comment: А как это сделать?

Comment: Как на скриншотах в этом ответе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1410299/1365

Comment: Появляется "Can't use Subversion command line client svn The path to the Subversion executable is probably wrong"

Comment: Это вы где-то не там настраиваете, скорее всего в Settings в разделе связанным с Subversion. Нужно в настройках запуска (run/debug configuration)

Comment: Там и настраиваю

Comment: Выложите скриншот где настраиваете и где это сообщение возникает

Comment: Всё, то, что там было исправила, но старая проблема осталась (см.скрины)

Comment: Посмотрите что выведет `print(sys.stdout.fileno())`. Если None, значит таким способом перемещать курсор выше в PyCharm не получится.

Comment: Единичку выводит

Comment: Значит `print(curses.tigetstr('cuu1'))` выведет None. Я не в курсе что это за метод, и что он должен возвращать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Действительно, дело было в функциях из библиотеки curses. Нашла управляющие последовательности и начала перемещать каретку с их помощью - заработало

```
x, y = 0, 0
def on_press(key):
    global player
    global x
    global y
    try:
        if (key.char == 'A' or key.char == 'a') and x>=0:
            sys.stdout.write("\033[2D")#влево
            x-=1
        elif (key.char == 'W' or key.char == 'w') and y<4:
            sys.stdout.write("\033[A")#верх
            y+=1
        elif (key.char == 'D' or key.char == 'd') and  x<4:
            sys.stdout.write("\033[2C")#вправо
            x+=1
        elif (key.char == 'S' or key.char == 's') and y>=0:
            sys.stdout.write("\033[B")#вниз
            y-=1
        elif key.char == 'Q' or key.char == 'q':
            player = get_player(player)
            sys.stdout.write(chars[player])
            sys.stdout.write("\033[C")
            readA()
            #printA()
            #print(listener.running)
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```