# Pycharm input() при Emulate terminal in console output

Tags: python, pycharm

Внезапно очень странно стал работать `input()` при включенной эмуляции терминала.

Мне эта эмуляция нужна, у меня там иначе не выводится кое какая информация из `subprocess`'а.

Мой код (тестовый проект из 2 строк, создан для теста):

```
sft = input("Enter text: ")
print(sft)
```

Что я вижу при запуске:

```
D:\PyProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:\PyProjects\pythonProject\main.py 
Enter folder address:
```

Если я начну туда чего то вводить, к примеру, `test` - я ничего не увижу. Вообще, примерно как это выглядит при вводе пароля рута в линуксах - пустая строка без изменения положения курсора. Но, как показывает практика - *сам ввод будет происходить*.

Если я введу слово и нажму на Enter **два** раза, я увижу на экране:

```
D:\PyProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:\PyProjects\pythonProject\main.py 
Enter folder address: test

Process finished with exit code 0
```

По виду похоже, что `print()` срабатывает в ту же строку.

Мб кто в курсе, как это пофиксить, не отказываясь от эмуляции терминала?

Comment: Возможно как-то связано с этим: [Второй input в PyCharm не работает (возвращает пустую строку)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1410280)

Comment: Вообще, терминал в PyCharm — это какой-то лютый глюкодром, я полностью отказался от его использования и использую обычный системный терминал

Comment: Наберите type D:\PyProjects\pythonProject\main.py и посмотрите, что там...

Comment: andreymal возможно, да... вот только у меня именно на эмуляции проблемы, без эмуляции все работает.

Comment: Виктор,
```sft = input("Enter folder address: ") 
print(sft)```
Все.